# Jboss AS 7 Maximum number of threads (64) created for connector with address /0.0.0.0 and port 8009

Tags: java, apache, jboss

I am experiencing an issue with a JBoss AS 7.1.1. The scenario is, I have an Apache HTTPD server in front, connected to JBoss using AJP running a Spring application.
Sometimes I get the error:

```
Maximum number of threads (64) created for connector with address /0.0.0.0 and port 8009
```

I have changed the configuration to include the max-connections flag in the AJP connector:

```
<connector name="ajp" protocol="AJP/1.3" scheme="http" socket-binding="ajp" max-connections="1000"/>
```

This, unfortunately hasn't fixed the issue. Can anyone point me in the right direction regarding this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for maxThreads instead?

> **maxThreads**
>
> The maximum number of request processing threads to be created by this Connector, which therefore determines the maximum
> number of simultaneous requests that can be handled. If not specified,
> this attribute is set to 200.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/ajp.html